# ¿Se vota poco en este Stack?

Tags: discusión

Acabo de aportar mi contribución a una de las preguntas más recientes del foro: "[¿Palabra adecuada para referirse a un retiro anticipado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14809/5481)" en forma de una respuesta y un upvote para la pregunta.

Al llegar, la pregunta, que llevaba publicada 16 horas, tenía unas 40 visitas, cero votos y cinco respuestas, todas ellas con cero votos menos una que tenía un único voto negativo. Ninguna de las respuestas parecía satisfacer completamente la pregunta, así que aporté mi respuesta.

Sin embargo, me pareció llamativo que la pregunta no tuviera más votos. Al fin y al cabo, si alguien se molesta en responder una pregunta la debe encontrar al menos mínimamente interesante.

Me pregunto, ¿Se vota *poco* en este stack? Y entiendo que es Beta y que las preguntas nuevas llegan con cuentagotas, por lo tanto quizá no tengamos tantos usuarios como otros stacks o los usuarios no visiten con tanta frecuencia.

Por esta razón, he querido abrir este hilo de discusión para saber si la comunidad de Spanish.SE piensa que se vota poco (o no), o si las preguntas y respuestas no tienen "calidad" suficiente (y por tanto no reciben tantos votos, y quizá tengamos que hacer alguna otra cosa al respecto), si es que "somos pocos" y sólo hay un núcleo pequeño de usuarios participando activamente en tareas de "moderación" (revisando posts, recompensado buenas preguntas y respuestas y contribuyendo con comentarios a mejorar las mismas, marcando esas "respuestas que no lo son", etc.) o si es por completo otra cosa.

No lo calificaría de "problema", pero sí me gustaría saber la opinión de la gente al respecto. Si alguien más lo nota o lo piensa, o si la situación es lo normal, dado lo que hay.

Al fin y al cabo Stack Exchange está *gamificado* y recompensamos y estimulamos preguntas de calidad mediante votos. De la misma manera que marcamos cosas como "off topic" porque "en el foro queremos preguntas de este o tal tipo y con este formato" los votos son una parte fundamental del Stack. No solo los votos están diseñados para animar al contenido de calidad, sino que hay incluso medallas que se obtienen por votar.

Comment: Por cierto, acabo de ver que Fundéu recomienda ["ludificación", mejor que "gamificación" como traducción de _gamification_](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/ludificacion-mejor-que-gamificacion-como-traduccion-de-gamification-1390/)

Comment: +1 porque yo tambien pienso que se vota poco :P

Answer (score 8):

¡Interesante pregunta!

Creo que este sitio tiene algún problema y las [estadísticas en Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) pueden ayudarnos a hacer una reflexión: tenemos muchas visitas pero poca participación.

En Stack Overflow me encuentro con frecuencia con el mismo caso que mencionas: muchas respuestas, bastantes visitas pero poco voto. En general, yo eso lo achaco a la "gamificación" de la pregunta/respuesta, por la cual las personas que responden no votan otras respuestas para que la suya no quede "rebajada" y no sea tan visible para la siguiente parsona que entre en la página. Es decir, si votas las otras respuestas, la tuya tiene menos votos y, probablemente, el autor de la pregunta acabará aceptando una de las más votadas en lugar de la tuya.

Parece pues que debemos centrarnos en:

- conseguir que la gente que entra en la página se registre en ella. "Avid users" en las estadísticas aparece como "Excellent", pues indica que hay bastantes usuarios con bastante reputación. Sin embargo, sospecho que bastantes de ellos ya no entran en el sitio con demasiada frecuencia. ¿Podemos recuperarlos?
- conseguir una mayor colaboración entre usuarios, para que votarse entre ellos, recomendar mejoras en las respuestas, etc. sea más frecuente. Mirando preguntas/respuestas de hace unos años, veo que había mayor colaboración y debate debajo de cada respuesta. ¿Tal vez algún veterano nos puede indicar qué podemos haber perdido en este tiempo para que ya no tengamos una comunidad tan activa?

Comment: Muy buen punto lo de la competitividad. Creo que hay una medalla "Sportman" si mal no recuerdo, que premia que votes otras respuestas en preguntas donde ya hay una respuesta tuya. La _gamificación_ da para mucha discusión pero creo que al cabo del tiempo en este sitio otros +10 puntos o otra medallita dejan de tener importancia. Al final, una buena respuesta o una buena pregunta es una recompensa en sí misma y si alguien estuviese aquí sólo por puntos (!?) terminaría dejando esto por aburrimiento. Completamente de acuerdo con lo que indicas en los dos "bullet points"

Comment: Con respecto a "gamificacion".  Los autores de Stackexchange pensaban que los participantes iban a gamificar porque eso sucede en todas las comunidades cibernéticas.  Diseñaron el sistema para que el proceso de optimizar reputación apoyara el proceso de añadir aportes beneficentes.

Comment: O sea, no se trata de evitar gamificación sino de utilizarla.

Comment: @WalterMitty totalmente de acuerdo. Sin embargo, la experiencia muestra que en algunos casos la gamificación también tiene la contraparte de favorecer los comportamientos "tácticos" para que la aportación de uno sobresalga respecto el resto.

Comment: @fedorqui totalmente de acuerdo.  Hay una correlación entre gamificación y hacking, que contrae consecuencias malas (y a veces buenas).

Comment: Desde luego, yo voto todo lo que me parece útil, interesante, trabajado, etc. Y no me preocupo de si mi respuesta pueda descender en el podio. Lo importante es la Comunidad, no el individuo, ¿no?

Answer (score 8):

Me parece que se vota poco en este Stack.  El voto para una respuesta indica que la respuesta es correcta y útil.  Son pocos los que tienen la tendencia de votar con respecto a las respuestas que se ofrecen.  Tal vez por falta de confianza, o por falta de interés.

Con respecto a la cantidad de respuestas que responden a cada pregunta, eso se debe, en parte, al hecho que el idioma varía un poco entre un país y otro.

Hace tiempo, yo opinaba que la baja votación por mis respuestas era porque eran de baja calidad.  Pero tal vez no.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Creo que se ve demasiado el voto como "recompensar a alguien con puntos por sus post" y se olvida que el voto es también un ejercicio de "validación". Muchas veces se ven comentarios de "+1. Esto es correcto" o similares, que son necesariamente redundantes con el voto positivo. Parece que votar "costase" o que hay que ser _exigentes_ con el contenido del post, cuando básicamente es otro ejercicio de moderación del contenido más que prácticamente todos los usuarios pueden hacer.

Comment: Respecto _la cantidad de respuestas que responden a cada pregunta, eso de debe, en parte, al hecho que el idioma varía un poco entre un país y otro_, precisamente sería interesante que hubiera distintas respuestas que aplicaran a diferentes regiones.

Answer (score 7):

Estoy de acuerdo en general. Pienso que esta comunidad vota poco, pero pienso que vota poco por *olvido* no por falta de razones.

Por otro lado este stack da **muchas** respuestas a una sola pregunta, comparado con otros stacks como por ejemplo Arcade donde la mayoría de preguntas tienen una sola respuesta pero muchos votos. Pienso nuestra comunidad es más activa proporcionalmente por el número de respuestas respecto al número de preguntas.

Tenemos que idear una estrategia para motivar a los usuarios a votar más. Personalmente no me había dado cuenta, pero ahora que lo mencionas pienso sí es el caso. Hay que comentar más y darle a saber a los usuarios que tienen la opción de votar y que deberían usarla.

Comment: "Tenemos que idear una estrategia para motivar a los usuarios a votar más." Completamente de acuerdo. Creo que recompensar las buenas preguntas es el primer paso para animar a esos usuarios a seguir usando este Stack como recurso académico. Dadas las estadísticas de este Stack, lo único que necesitaría para pasar de Beta es más preguntas. Lo demás ya lo tiene casi todo.