# Propuesta: Concurso de "Las mejores respuestas" de cada trimestre

Tags: discusión, promoción-de-la-comunidad

Como anticipamos en [las ideas de la retrospectiva de 2017](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2766/5481), los moderadores hemos estado trabajando en incorporar un concurso-recopilación con las mejores respuestas de cada trimestre. Esto es algo que sabemos que [se hace en otros stacks](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-1st-quarter-of-2017) y creemos que podría ser beneficioso para el nuestro.

Básicamente, crearíamos un meta-post con la pregunta "¿Cuáles han sido las mejores respuestas de [tal trimestre de tal año]?", que incluiría un enlace a una consulta (a http://data.stackexchange.com) que tendría un enlace a una lista de respuestas publicadas ese trimestre. Responderíamos con publicaciones con un enlace a una respuesta y una breve explicación de por qué pensamos que ha sido una de las mejores preguntas del trimestre. El sistema de votos del stack convertiría entonces el hilo en una especie de "concurso de popularidad". Se admitirían múltiples "entradas" por usuario (no múltiples respuestas en una misma publicación, pero sí más de una respuesta por usuario) y se podrían nominar las respuestas de uno mismo.

A las respuestas con más votos les daríamos una recompensa (cortesía mía) de, propongamos, 150, 100 y 50 puntos al primer, segundo y tercer puesto respectivamente.

### Objetivos (¿por qué hacemos esto?)

Creemos que esto puede ser interesante porque:

- Añadiría un pelín más de motivación a crear buenas respuestas de calidad.
- Motivaría para revisar contenido del sitio. Tenemos grandes aportaciones en el stack que nos han hecho aprender un montón de cosas. Ahora, con los pocos post que tenemos por día parece que es fácil estar al tanto de todos, pero al revisar cuáles han sido los mejores post de un trimestre (tanto al evaluar respuestas como al ver las propuestas de otros) podemos encontrarnos con algo que no vimos o con algo que al releer podemos entender y aprender mejor (un poco de refuerzo).
- Daría visibilidad a potenciales joyas que en su momento pasaron desapercibidas.
- Animaría a votar buenas preguntas, si no lo hicimos en su momento. [Me repito hasta la saciedad con este tema](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481), pero al premiar el contenido de calidad recompensamos a quienes dedican su tiempo a crearlo, validamos el contenido del sitio y damos reputación a usuarios, para que se puedan hacer cargo de tareas de moderación. Tenemos incluso multitud de medallas que se entregan por tareas relacionadas con votos.
- Conocer post existentes ayudaría a identificar duplicados.
- Sería divertido (miradlo como un "[translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) para Meta").

No sería dificil ir refinando la idea a través de sucesivas iteraciones del "concurso", pero como en todo post-discusión queremos dar voz antes de implementarlo para expresar cualquier tipo de duda, queja, oposición o idea que pueda contribuir a mejorarlo. Por ejemplo:

- la consulta, ¿debería ser lo más "ciega" posible, para no tener un sesgo de ir solo a revisar las preguntas que ya tienen más votos o a nuestros usuarios favoritos?
- dudas sobre el mecanismo, como "¿puedo nominar una pregunta del [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) si me ha hecho aprender algo muy interesante o es sobresaliente en otro aspecto?"

Comment: Cuenta conmigo para dar las recompensas que sean necesarias.

Comment: @walen, me habría gustado premiar también post-respuesta. Parece que en la filosofía de los stacka las respuestas ofrecen mucho más valor que las preguntas a la comunidad. Supongo que tendré que conformarme con recompensar buenas respuestas.

Comment: Una pregunta.  Teníamos hasta hoy para hacer propuestas.  Ahora, nos podrían dar un par de días más para considerar las candidatas y votar?

Comment: Entiendo que, por el tiempo transcurrido, este proyecto se quedó en la estacada, ¿no? Yo soy nuevo aquí, pero me parece que era una excelente idea.

Comment: @karloswitt hicimos algunas ediciones, que puedes ver navegando por la etiqueta [meta-tag:promoción-de-la-comunidad]. La última es la del [primer trimestre de 2018](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2883/1674). La falta de participación motivó que Diego planteara [Mejores preguntas del trimestre: Buena idea, mala implementación](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/1674)

Answer (score 5):

Me parece una gran idea por la parte de dar visibilidad a las respuestas y premiar buen contenido (en un stack en el que, habiendo tan pocos votantes, puede costar un poco conseguir reputación si no estás todos los días en la brecha).

El tema de las recompensas, creo que convendría aplicarlo solo a usuarios que aún no hayan alcanzado cierta reputación, por ejemplo 5000 (que es cuando te dan el último [privilegio de moderación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). De lo contrario, nos arriesgamos a que las recompensas vayan a parar siempre a usuarios que ya de por sí suelen ser los más votados, con lo que el concurso perdería parte de su sentido. De hecho, quizá sería mejor aplicar ese límite al concurso en sí, por los mismos motivos.

En cuanto a las respuestas del TG, bueno :D Dudo que nadie las vaya a encontrar "mejores" que las respuestas a preguntas normales, que son mucho más informativas, pero no pasa nada por incluirlas.

Un apunte sobre las recompensas y el [mecanismo de *bounties* de SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/362105):

> #### What is the minimum amount of rep I can offer a bounty for?
>
> For most questions, 50 reputation. There are some exceptions, though:
>
> - If you have already answered the question before, the minimum bounty offer is 100.
> - If you have already offered a bounty on the question before, the minimum offer is double your last offer (see below).

Comento esto porque, para poder dar recompensas de 50, 100 y 150, seguramente os tendréis que repartir el trabajo :) Nos pasó con el especial de TG ;)

Comment: If part of the motivation is to counter the lack of votes on this site then perhaps we should limit ourselves to questions posed by people with a reputation below a certain level. Perhaps 1000 (one thousand)?

Comment: I think the last moderator privilege is at 3500? I suggested 1000 because I felt I should choose a level from which i could not personally benefit.

Comment: Me parece interesante. Como [señala fedorqui](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2777/5481) un pequeño porcentaje de usuarios acapara un gran porcentaje del "tráfico" de posts/reps y no es el objetivo de esta actividad dar más todavía a estos usuarios (aunque lo mereciesen). Parece ser que solo tenemos [20 usuarios que pasan de los 5000](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/163/alltime/spanish/2011-11-15), no todos son muy activos en el stack, y estamos en "perpetua beta". Aun así, dejaría que cualquier respuesta pudiese participar, aunque luego no sea recompensada.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar ya con el último semestre/trimestre de 2017, abogo por no hacer filtro por usuarios. Si luego vemos que se desmadra, ya perfilamos. Es que si esperamos un poco ya no nos acordaremos de qué se coció en el sitio durante ese trimestre :)

Por ejemplo, con este filtro tenemos las respuestas del cuarto trimestre de 2017: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2017-10..2017-12

Tomando de la pregunta equivalente en Movies.SE, [Favourite questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4104/4078), tendríamos estas consultas para Spanish.SE:

- [Preguntas del cuarto trimestre con más visitas](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Preguntas del cuarto trimestre con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Respuestas del cuarto trimestre con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)

Comment: @walen sí, sí. Solamente añadí esta respuesta para reactivar la iniciativa de Diego y a modo de ejemplo. En breve lo publicamos.

Comment: "Si luego vemos que se desmadra, ya perfilamos", sí, mis idea exactamente. Necesito un poco de tiempo para redactar el post-meta, pero creo que va a ser mejor publicar y "corregir sobre la marcha" (en sucesivas ediciones" que intentar tener todos los cabos atados ahora. La propuesta no tiene ningún negativo, así que no creo que nadie se oponga a seguir adelante. Además, será más fácil ver qué campos queremos ofrecer en la consulta mientras estemos haciendo uso "real" de la misma (yo había pensado usar data.stackexchange.com, pero el enfoque de fedorqui me gusta mucho más).