# Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2017 Q4)

Tags: discusión, respuestas, promoción-de-la-comunidad, contenido

### Resultados

**Primer puesto** (6 votos): [En el DLE ¿hay más casos de acepciones tan localizadas regionalmente como la 5ª de “cuesco”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23640/5481) de [Angus](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/408/angus)

**Segundos puestos** (compartido con 4 votos cada una):

- [¿Hay alguna diferencia sustancial entre las dos primeras acepciones de “barrer”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23519/5481) de [Mauricio Martínez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17686/mauricio-martinez).
- [¿Existen palabras con construcción similar a “penúltimo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23281/5481) de [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego)

<sub>Terminado el plazo para votar más el pequeño periodo de gracia que habéis pedido, paso a dar por finalizada la primera edición de este concurso. Enhorabuena a los ganadores y gracias a todos los que habéis participado proponiendo respuestas. Ya he puesto recompensas en las preguntas de las respuestas ganadoras. Tengo que esperar 24 horas para asignarlas, así que en un par de días las otorgaré a las respuestas ganadoras.</sub>

---

El tiempo pasa volando y más en internet. En este pedacito de la red que es Spanish.SE nos pasamos el día preguntando y contestando y, como por suerte tenemos bastante movimiento, resulta que lo que hoy se contesta magníficamente, mañana corre el riesgo de quedar olvidado por la nueva hornada de publicaciones de gran calidad.

Es por ello que, como adelantamos en [*Propuesta: Concurso de “Las mejores respuestas” de cada trimestre*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2773/5481), ponemos en marcha esta iniciativa con la que queremos mirar por el retrovisor (¡como con [la retrospectiva anual](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2765/1674)!) y cada tres meses observar con cierta calma qué joyas nos ofrecieron los usuarios en el trimestre anterior.

La cuestión es fácil: bucea entre las respuestas y contesta a esta pregunta proponiendo cada vez una respuesta diferente. Si quieres proponer dos respuestas, publica dos respuestas a esta pregunta, y así sucesivamente. Pasadas dos semanas, las tres respuestas con mejor puntuación serán las ganadoras y recibirán una recompensa en puntos.

Reglas:

- Indica cuáles son para ti las mejores respuestas publicadas entre el 1 de octubre y el 31 de diciembre de 2017.
- Cualquier respuesta es válida: pueden ser del [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), pueden ser de cualquier usuario, pueden contener cualquier etiqueta.
- Se puede hacer desde hoy 30 de enero hasta el domingo 11 de febrero.
- Nomina respuestas, pero no olvides añadir una breve explicación de por qué te parece buena, qué has aprendido con ella, qué destacas de la respuesta, etc.
- En paralelo, ve votando las otras respuestas aportadas al concurso.
- Cuentan solamente los votos positivos, por lo que si una propuesta no te gusta, simplemente no la votes y ya está.

Y para facilitar la búsqueda, estas son las respuestas publicadas en ese rango de fechas:

[Respuestas entre 1 de octubre y 31 de diciembre de 2017](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20created%3A2017-10..2017-12) (hay cerca de 700)

Para facilitar la búsqueda, también puedes usar las siguientes consultas:

- [Preguntas del cuarto trimestre con más visitas](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Preguntas del cuarto trimestre con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Respuestas del cuarto trimestre con más votos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)

Hagan juego señores :)

---

Dado que esta es la primera edición del concurso, céntrate por favor solo en el concurso en sí en esta publicación, y utiliza el ya mencionado [Propuesta: Concurso de “Las mejores respuestas” de cada trimestre](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2773/5481) para feedback, ideas, quejas y otros comentarios para mejorar la mecánica del concurso.

Comment: Preferiría que se propusiera a la respuesta, no a la persona.  Una persona podría tener dos respuestas excelentes.

Comment: @aparente001 es lo que está ocurriendo. Quizá nadie ha propuesto dos o más preguntas del mismo usuario, pero varios usuarios tienen más de una respuesta suya nominada. Hay quien dice "Nomino a userABC por la respuesta XYZ" y hay quien dice "Nomino la respuesta XYZ de usuarioABC", pero eso no quiere decir que solo vayan a nominar una única pregunta de ese usuario. Con 13 nominaciones de 5 usuarios distintos, pues no se aprecia que alguien esté nominado más de una resp del mismo usuario, pero se puede.

Comment: **Nota: se ha bloqueado esta pregunta y todas sus respuestas para que no se puedan votar y, así, se respeten las votaciones existentes el día que se cerró el concurso. No hagáis caso del motivo (not good blabla), pues no había ninguno realmente pertinente.**

Answer (score 3):

Nomino a angus por su trabajada y elaborada respuesta en *[En el DLE ¿hay más casos de acepciones tan localizadas regionalmente como la 5ª de “cuesco”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23640/12637)*, que nos descubrió las definiciones más localizadas del diccionario.

Answer (score 2):

Propongo [¿Hay alguna diferencia sustancial entre las dos primeras acepciones de “barrer”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23519/5481) de [Mauricio Martínez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17686/mauricio-martinez).

La pregunta de Blonfu es ya de por sí bastante buena, pero me gusta como contesta Mauricio explicando el matiz. Yo no habría dicho que las definiciones son redundantes, pero con la breve pero sencilla explicación de Mauricio, queda claro que una es una actividad más general y rutinario y otra es una más "dirigida".

Answer (score 2):

Genial respuesta de Guifa en [¿Demasiado o demasiada?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22766/5481). Esta es otra de esas preguntas (genial pregunta de Mauricio Martínez, por cierto) en las que yo habría pensado un poco, habría dicho "está mal" y no le habría dado más vueltas. Esta brillante respuesta nos recuerda que hay palabras que pueden ser adjetivos y también adverbios según el caso.

Answer (score 2):

Propongo [¿Qué tan válido es el doble posesivo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23455/5481), ya que esta es una de esas cosas que a priori yo habría pensado que están mal dichas, y luego resulta que hay una razón para ello (evitar la ambigüedad del posesivo `su`). Gracias Blonfu!

Answer (score 2):

Nomino a Diego por su respuesta a una pregunta de etimología, *[¿Existen palabras con construcción similar a “penúltimo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23281/12637)*, de esas que te iluminan y de repente empiezas a entender el por qué de algunas palabras.

Answer (score 2):

La increible traducción de Walen en el juego especial de Navidad [Translation Golf - Christmas Special Edition!](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23680/14069) merece estar en esta lista. Mantuvo la métrica a lo largo de todo el poema, también siguió la estructura de rima y al mismo tiempo lo escribió con gracia y estilo. Creo que es el mejor [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) hasta la fecha aunque no sea especialmente corto.

Answer (score 2):

Nomino la respuesta de Charlie a [¿Por qué no decimos "crocodilo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22596/por-qu%C3%A9-no-decimos-crocodilo/22602#22602), más que nada porque desde que la leí no paro de comentárselo a todo el mundo (*"¿Sabías que en realidad al principio se decía crocodilo, y luego se cambió?"*) :D
Además creo que es una respuesta que nos enseña a ser un poco más humildes ante las personas que hablan "mal" (p. ej. "murciégalo"), pues quizá las palabras que usan resulten tener raíces más antiguas y cultas de lo que nos creemos.

Answer (score 2):

Propongo la [respuesta de **guifa** en ¿Por qué antes “lector” se decía “letor”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23218/1674).

Me gusta, como siempre en guifa, que mezcle revisión histórica con comparación con otros idiomas. Además, como también ocurre con frecuencia con sus respuestas, añade una capa de abstracción que nos permite entender mejor nuestro idioma.

Comment: No puedo dejar de votar esta propuesta después del comentario que le puse a su respuesta... :-D

Comment: @Charlie jajaja pues no la había leído, pero comparto el sentimiento

Answer (score 1):

En [“Kyrie eleison”: does Spanish have any Greek sayings, like it does Latin? If not, why?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22791/5481) [Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1768/gorpik) nos recuerda que además de latinismos y anglicismos, tenemos expresiones de otros idiomas (en este caso griego) en Español.

Su respuesta me gusta especialmente (nada que desmerecer a la de [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22794/5481) en el mismo hilo) por haber hecho referencia al rey espartano Leónidas, incluida la explicación sobre el término [lacónico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ml6X01U).

Answer (score 1):

Propongo [Is it correct to say “Dejemos trabajar a la fiscalía, *sino* vamos a enturbiar la investigación” or should we use “si no” instead?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23600/5481) de [Walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13628/walen).

Ese es uno de los errores que más cometo al escribir ("Si no" vs. "sino") y me vino bien refrescar con el enlace aportado. Me gusta que Walen se atreve a denunciar

> In general, I'd recommend not to take any mass media as "reputable source" when it comes to grammar use.

Entiendo que nuestros los periodistas pueden tener ahora unas fechas de entrega draconianas para sus artículos, debido a la naturaleza de la prensa online, pero queda muy mal estar leyendo un periódico y encontrar faltas de ortografía (cosa que cada vez me sucede con mayor frecuencia). Da muy mala imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo la [respuesta comunitaria a Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23618/14069), autor: community wiki.

Esta pregunta y respuesta representa un gran logro para nuestro sitio.  Es fruto de un proceso de discusión amplia y creo que su publicación en el sitio principal ha sido motivo de gran satisfacción para todos.

Es una respuesta completa y amplia del tema.  Está bien organizada y formateada.  Y representa una colaboración bastante amplia de diversos participantes del sitio.

Si puediera votar por una sola respuesta en este concurso, sería esta.

Comment: ¡Qué bien verla nominada aquí!

Answer (score 1):

Propongo la respuesta nueva a [What are some effective ways a foreign speaker can improve pronunciation in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23439/9385), autor Lisa Beck.

Es una respuesta redactada por alguien que se esfuerza por mejorarse en su manejo del idioma.  Es una respuesta amplia y bien formateada.  Creo que será útil para muchos estudiantes del español.

La pregunta se cerró hace poco pero de todas maneras me gustaría que se reconociera esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Me gusta  [¿Cómo se denomina a un invento extremadamente complejo para resolver algo sencillo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23470/5481) de user18111 por la sencillez a la par que utilidad de la misma. Las preguntas de [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino) son unas de mis favoritas!