# Mejores preguntas del trimestre: Buena idea, mala implementación

Tags: discusión, respuestas, promoción-de-la-comunidad, contenido

A fecha de hoy hemos celebrado dos veces el concurso de las mejores preguntas del trimestre:

- [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2017 Q4)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2787/5481)
- [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2018 Q1)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2883/5481)

Como se explicaba en la [propuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2773/5481), los objetivos son múltiples:

- Motivar un poco más a escribir respuestas de gran calidad
- Motivar a revisar (y votar) respuestas existentes en las que no hayamos reparado
- Dar mayor visibilidad a grandes contribuciones que quizá pasaron desapercibidas
- Hacer un concurso, para entretenernos de paso que hacemos promoción de la comunidad y de contenido

La verdad es que creo que si preguntase si es una buena idea, todo el mundo diría que sí y que deberíamos seguir haciéndolo. Por otro lado, es bastante obvio que la implementación no es la adecuada, y debemos hacer algunas mejoras.

De acuerdo, este *stack* está en perpetuo *beta* y la participación en meta es incluso más baja y lenta que en el sitio principal (aunque también vaya por temporadas). Sin embargo, estoy seguro de que podemos hacer algo más para mejorar la implementación de este concurso.

Esta meta pregunta es simplemente un post discusión para poder hacer una *tormenta de ideas* sobre cosas que podemos mejorar y cómo hacerlo. Por ejemplo, qué hacer para facilitar la búsqueda de respuestas del trimestre (ahora se facilitan unas listas con varios criterios, como preguntas con más visitas o más votos. Quizá otros criterios faciliten encontrar mejores candidatas para el concurso) o cómo resolver empates (que hacemos si tenemos 10 propuestas y empatan todas en votos? Empate múltiple con máxima recompensa para todas?). Es el plazo para votar adecuado?

Comment: Where can I start putting my proposals for Best Answers Second Quarter 2018?  Could you open it up officially, please?  It's so much easier for me to add one to the list of candidates if I can add it when I see it instead of waiting until the quarter is over.  I thought that was the outcome but I can't find such a question on Meta.

Comment: You can favorite the question and then nominate the answer once the poll is open. See walen's proposal, to nominate only users under a certain amount of rep, which we didn't clarify. See also charlie's proposal to add visibility to candidate answers. We haven't clarified yet these things, so I don't think that we should move forward opening the polls.

Answer (score 3):

Como esto es en plan tormenta de ideas, a ver qué os parece esto: a mí una de las cosas que me resulta más complicado es buscar las respuestas que quiero proponer, porque para cuando ha terminado el trimestre se me han olvidado muchas de ellas incluso aunque en su momento pensara que son buenas candidatas. Así que propongo:

- Abrir una pregunta "featured" en meta nada más empezar el trimestre, donde cada persona tenga una respuesta en la que ir añadiendo las respuestas que más le han gustado. Sería como una especie de bloc de notas, donde los votos no importarían. Si veo una respuesta que me ha parecido especialmente trascendente, la añado a esa pregunta de meta.
- Cuando acabe el trimestre, se cierra esa pregunta y se abre una nueva con el concurso en sí, y se procede a trasladar a esta todas las anotaciones de la pregunta anterior, comenzando con las votaciones.

El único problema (que no es tal) es si dos personas apuntan la misma respuesta. Con que se coordinen mínimamente será suficiente: que uno la ponga y el otro la vote.

Comment: No olvides que puedes **marcar preguntas como favoritas**, y así puedes poner un "flag" de recordatorio a preguntas que contienen respuestas que quieres proponer. Una vez terminado el concurso las puedes sacar de tu lista de favoritas.

Comment: Qué buena idea. Además, va en la línea de lo que hacen en [movies.se], que es de donde cogimos esta idea con @Diego. Allí tienen el concurso tipo [Rewards for the best answer from the 2nd quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2876/4078) pero luego [Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2872/4078). La única pequeña pega que le encuentro es que seguramente arrastraría votos a la respuesta, con lo que no podría cumplirse lo que sugiere walen de limitar a respuestas con poca puntuación.

Answer (score 3):

Mi propuesta no está a la altura de la de Charlie, pero bueno, espero que también aporte algo :D

Tal como explica Diego, el objetivo del concurso era, básicamente, premiar respuestas de calidad para motivar a sus autores a seguir participando a ese nivel, así como dar votos y visibilidad a buenas respuestas cuya puntuación no esté a la altura.

Revisemos ahora si las entradas participantes son el tipo de usuarios y respuestas a los que efectivamente resulta útil y necesario darles tal empujón:

- Concurso 2017-Q4

  - Autores participantes / **ganadores** (y su reputación): Charlie (36k), **Diego (31k)**, guifa (22k), walen (14k), Gorpik (8k), **angus (5k)**, **Mauricio Martinez (4k)**, blonfu (4k), Lisa Beck (2k), user18111 (borrado).
  - Puntuación de las respuestas participantes / **ganadoras**: +13, **+12**, **+11**, +11, +9, +9, **+8**, +8, +8, +6, +3, +2.
- Concurso 2018-Q1

  - Autores participantes / **ganadores** (y su reputación): Charlie (36k), **Diego (31k)**, guifa (22k), pablodf76 (14k), rsanchez (4k), **Lisa Beck (2k)**, **ukemi (2k)**.
  - Puntuación de las respuestas participantes / **ganadoras**: **+17**, +11, +9, +7, **+6**, **+6**, +4, +4.

En mi opinión, y creo que varios estaréis de acuerdo, no están alineados los resultados del concurso con los objetivos, por dos motivos.

Primero: casi todos los usuarios nominados son de los más activos y con mayor reputación del sitio: **todos los participantes formamos parte del ["top 20" del último año](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year), salvo angus**. Era de esperar, por número de aportaciones aunque sea. Pero la cuestión es que la calidad de las respuestas de estos usuarios es ya de por sí bastante alta.
¿Realmente necesitamos los usuarios "top" más recompensas? Al permitir que participen respuestas como las nuestras ¿no estaremos desperdiciando la oportunidad de encontrar esas "joyas ocultas" de las que hablábamos? ¿Hasta qué punto motiva a los usuarios más noveles, y con quizá gran potencial, el ver que la mayoría de candidatas son publicaciones de "los de siempre"?

Segundo: casi todas las respuestas tenían, ya antes de participar en el concurso, una puntuación por encima de la media del stack ([que es 3, más o menos](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/revision/843898/1041579/mean-answer-score-for-the-last-year)). Es cierto que, a día de hoy, algunos de esos votos pueden haber venido precisamente gracias al concurso, pero **la mayoría de respuestas andaban ya por +5 o +6 (el doble de la media) cuando se admitieron a concurso**. (Por no hablar de los *hits* del cocodrilo y los guisantes, que estaban ya en +10 o +12... ¿Tendrá algo que ver el color verde?)
De nuevo la pregunta que planteo es: ¿favorece a los objetivos que gran parte de la visibilidad adicional que proporciona el concurso vaya a parar a respuestas que ya tenían visibilidad suficiente, a la vista de los votos con los que contaban?

En mi opinión, **los objetivos del concurso se cumplirán mejor si se establece un límite de reputación y de puntuación para participar**. Premiar a respuestas con pocos votos y a usuarios que hasta el momento no han participado mucho o no han recibido el reconocimiento que merecen, creo que beneficiará más al stack. No establecer un límite puede derivar en concursos endogámicos que, aunque divertidos y satisfactorios a nivel personal, poco aportan al crecimiento y evolución del sitio.
[El límite de reputación ya lo planteé en la propuesta inicial](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2774/13628), y recibí algunos comentarios a favor y algún otro en contra. No obstante y tras dejar pasar un par de ediciones para ver qué tal ha funcionado, creo que mi análisis era correcto.
El límite de puntuación de las respuestas, es algo que no me había planteado hasta ahora, pero creo que sería bueno establecerlo, por más o menos los mismos motivos que el de reputación. Intentando que sea de manera que no se favorezca injustamente a las respuestas hechas solo unos días antes del concurso (que siempre van a tener pocos votos y, por descontado, menos que las respuestas hechas al principio del trimestre).

También quiero decir que creo que **en lo que a premios finales se refiere nos hemos portado bastante bien, puesto que casi todos han caído en la "parte baja" de la escala**: de los cinco premiados, solo Diego tiene más de 5000 puntos de reputación.
Pero nadie nos dice que vaya a seguir siendo así en posteriores ediciones, de ahí mi propuesta de aplicar un límite.

Comment: Esta es una excelente crítica al mecanismo actual. Por motivos obvios los usuarios más activos y más participativos tienen más respuestas y estas suelen ser de mayor calidad (y por tanto con más votos). Dicho eso, tienes toda la razón, y estoy completamente de acuerdo con lo que propones. No queda claro, pero supongo que el límite serían esos 5000 que se necesitan en beta para obtener todos los privilegios?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un TLDR: por favor?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en el tema del límite de puntuación de la respuesta: para qué destacar supuestas joyas ocultas si de ocultas no tienen nada. Lo que no me convence es la idea de limitar quién puede optar a ellas: al fin y al cabo, la reputación de cada cual es algo cambiante e independiente de las publicaciones que publica.

Comment: Efectivamente, me expresé fatal. Mi punto es que la calidad de una publicación es _estable_ y la reputación de su autor algo cambiante. Tú argumentas que uno con bastante rep tiende a ofrecer respuestas buenas por regla general, y estoy de acuerdo. Sin embargo, la idea del concurso es encontrar _joyas_ y ahora sugerimos añadirle la coletilla _que pasaron desaparcibidas_. Dado que esto no es tan frecuente (somos pocos, las publicaciones están bastante expuestas), dejar de lado a los usuarios más activos me parece injusto para ellos.

Comment: ¿Y si se hace una segunda categoría en plan "Goya al actor revelación", que se premie a la respuesta con más votos de un usuario con menos de *x* reputación o algo así?

Answer (score 2):

Ampliando la propuesta de @Charlie, una posible idea que haría el concurso más visible para todos y por tanto atraería (quizá) más participación y más variedad de candidaturas (y más votos para éstas) sería **hacer uso de la funcionalidad de eventos** para promocionar y diferenciar las etapas de nominaciones y de votaciones.

Suponiendo que finalmente se hagan las nominaciones en un hilo y las votaciones en otro, podría crearse un evento para la fase de nominación, con explicación y fechas, y una vez completado se haría otro similar para la fase de votación. Aparte, claro, del uso que se quiera hacer del tag [featured](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) (aunque lo normal es que, entre evento y votaciones y demás, estos hilos se cuelen por sí solos en Hot Meta Posts).

Con solo un hilo, se podría hacer algo parecido, pero es más complicado.

Comment: Esta idea me gusta tanto como la de Charlie. // walen, me haces un favor, y pones un TLDR en tu otra respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

La clave aquí está en la falta de participación: pocas personas participan y todos con buena fe eligen respuestas excelentes. El resto de usuarios que leen la propuesta están de acuerdo y la votan positivamente. Resultado: pocas propuestas, todas ellas con muchos votos. Normalmente gana la que primero se propuso, pues ha sido vista por más gente y, por ende, ha arrastrado más votos.

Sugiero ser más [verboso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bbcnpQk), más explícito, para involucrar a más gente. Por ejemplo, cuando se publique aquí una sugerencia, poner un comentario en la respuesta original diciendo algo así como:

> Esta respuesta me parece excelente y pasó desapercibida por azares del destino. Por ello, la estoy nominando a la mejor respuesta del trimestre Qn en la publicación de Meta...

Comment: Nunca me hubiera imaginado que en español teníamos la palabra "verboso". Como el inglés "verbose"... ¡Qué curioso!