# Is there a way to recognize those who write an answer that gets anointed as canonical?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-canónicas

Writing [a canonical answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) is a lot of work. I wonder if we could come up with some way of recognizing authors of questions that get marked "canonical"?

How about a special badge?  Or jumpstart the author's progress towards a gold medal in that tag?  Something else?

Comment: If the answer is canonical should get more visibility. In a healthy stack people would exercise their votes to uphold good, useful and clear answers that show  effort. That eventually would grant the OP badges. So, if we had a decent level of participation, these users would eventually get "nice/good/great answer" + advance toward the tag badges. I don't know if sites can get their own badges and on top of that award then "on demand" (I think that there's a "I'm not a robot one that only some sites have and CM or mods award).

Comment: Preguntas relacionadas: [¿Se vota poco en este Stack?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481) (Creo que no merece la pena preguntar si se sigue votando poco en el stack, porque la mayoría de nuestros post de Meta tratan sobre la escasa participación). En su momento tuvimos una serie de ediciones del [concurso de mejores respuestas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2773/5481), precisamente para premiar a usuarios por respuestas notables y fomentar la participación. No salió como esperábamos, pero [aprendimos algunas cosas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/5481)

Comment: Another option could be awarding bounties to those questions. That would get the extra rep to those users and motivate + reward them. Could be useful if you wanted to move any of those users higher up in the [privilege list](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) so they can perform more useful tasks for the community (editing, reviewing, etc.)

Comment: Creo @Diego que el nivel de voto ha mejorado bastante estos años. [Hace cinco años](/a/378/1674) estábamos un poco flojos pero [creo que gracias a insistir en Meta con frecuencia hace un par de años] ahora [estamos mejor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4189/83), más o menos en la media de los sitios Stack. Eso sí, veo que se vota bastante lo nuevo, pero las publicaciones viejas es raro que vayan consiguiendo nuevos votos, probablemente por la escasez de nuevos usuarios. Los [votos de usuarios sin derecho a voto](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/636845) son buena pista.

Comment: @fedorqui - No entiendo "los votos de usuarios sin derecho a voto." Miré un poquito tu query.  No lo entendí, pero me asombra que una buena pregunta, vista 62,000 veces (!) solo hay recibido 3 votos. // ¿Nos precisa recibir más votos?

Comment: @apa son los votos emitidos por la gent que aún no puede votar. No se muestran en el contador de votos, pero sí se guardan. Haz una prueba: abre una página de Stack en modo privado (sin sesión abierta) y vota. Te dirá que no puedes, pero que gracias por la info. Son esos votos. Creo que hay que tomarlos 'with a grain of salt' pero sí pueden mostrar las cosas bien recibidas por usuarios anónimos

Comment: @fedorqui - ¡Ah!  Sí, he experimentado eso.  Leí algo en otro sitio de la red que me gustó, me asocié para poder votar, y no me aceptaron el voto.  Es extraña esa regla.  ¿Podríamos pedir que la cambien para los sitios pequeños?

Comment: Yo lo aprendí en [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/83), de Meta SOes. Tiene su lógica y está poco explicado, algún día podríamos analizar los resultados. Y no creo que haya nada cambiable allí, no olvidemos que SE hace poco caso a los sitios pequeños. Mejor esperar a que haya algo importante en los grandes (como lo de reducir los votos de cierre) y ponernos a rebufo para beneficiarnos de ello.

Comment: @fedorqui - Yo no soy tan cínique.  (¿Lo hice bien?  Es = cínic@.)  Aunque no seas muy optimista, ¿apoyas la propuesta si lo propongo cuando termine mi actual suspensión?  (Lo ideal sería que me ayudaras con la redacción.  Bueno, lo ideal ideal sería que lo postearas tú.)

Comment: No creo que resuelva ningún problema que tengamos ahora mismo. Me gusta que se exija un mínimo de reputación para votar positivamente y un poco más para hacerlo negativamente. Reducir estos umbrales provocaría cascadas de votos positivos de usuarios sin experiencia alguna y de negativos de usuarios de otros sitios por el simple hecho de registrarse. No lo veo, la verdad. Además, creo que hay otras cosas más útiles para el sitio, como lo de reducir el número de votos de cierre. Centrémonos en una cosa cada vez y aquí hablábamos de preguntas canónicas (fallo mío por desviarme :D)

Answer (score 1):

To me, canonical answers is something live, that grows and improves over time. Yes, we do have canonical Q&A posted with this intention, and we are very happy and grateful to those who posted them! However, I think most of the answers in [List of canonical questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) are a result of distilling: they were once posted as an answer to a specific topic, then got motion over time by a lot of visitors commenting, upvoting, suggesting modifications... until they became a beautiful thing that is very useful to many.

This is how I like to see the canonical questions. I guess I have some in Stack Overflow: posts with some hundreds of upvotes, hundreds of thousands of visits and quite a lot of edits by different users to polish the post. And this is, in my opinion, the best reward of these answers: to have others improve them, to get some comments showing gratitude (or even emails!), to have it referenced in other sites outside the Stack Exchange network.

I agree the gamification is cool and getting a badge can be nice, but after a while, once you get enough reputation to have all the privileges in the site, I think that getting human reward is way warmer than any badge. For this, I would say: **let's show gratitude by improving these answers, keeping them clean, expressing our gratitude to the authors and honouring their effort by linking them whenever it is necessary.**

Comment: Well, some side benefits of some special recognition could be that it might motivate people to write more canonical answers; and people might use the canonical Q-As more.  Also, maybe it would be a good thing to have more members of the site with a high level of privileges.  (But I do like what you said about the intrinsic reward as well.)